# pandas - efficient iterrow and replace

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to do this process more efficiently. Since my dataframe has about 100k rows and columns could contain up to 20k strings per row.

I want to remove words from a list if that word is in another list. Besides how big my data is my remove list is about 600k size wise.

I was hoping for a some sort of vectorized solution but not sure its possible.

What i'm currently doing

```
removelist = df2.words.tolist()
for row in df.itertuples():
   df.at[row.Index, 'tweet'] = [x for x in row.tweet if x not in removelist]
```

I know I can convert them to a set and do

```
set(row.tweet).intersection(screen)
```

but maintaining duplicates is pretty important. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
Sample data

```
df
                  tweet  user
0                  [@a]     1
1                  [@b]     2
2  [#c, #d, #e, #f, #e]     3
3                  [@g]     4

df2
    words
0  #d
1  @a
```

Desired ouput:

```
                       tweet  user
    0                  []       1
    1                  [@b]     2
    2      [#c, #e, #f, #e]     3
    3                  [@g]     4
```

Comment: it'll be good if you provide some sample data set and your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over `itertuples` is slow. I'd recommend using a list comprehension for maximum speed (since this isn't an operation that you can vectorise, this is likely your best bet):

```
removeset = set(df2.words.tolist())
df['tweet'] = [
     [j for j in i if j not in removeset] for i in df.tweet.tolist()
]
```